# How to authenticate a google forms api request in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-forms-api

I am trying to make a get request in flutter from the google forms api. My request looks something like below:

```
var response = await http.get(
  Uri.parse(
      'https://forms.googleapis.com/v1/forms/ID/responses'),
  headers: {
    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
        "STRING KEY",
  });
```

The issue is that when I created the credentials, I was given a json file and stuff like client ID instead of an api key. I was wondering how this could be used to authenticate an api request? The credentials page says this is a OAuth 2.0 Client ID credential type if that helps explain what information I have.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
var response = await http.get(
  Uri.parse(
      'https://forms.googleapis.com/v1/forms/ID/responses'),
  headers: {
    "Authorization":"STRING_KEY",
  });
```

Also if it is a bearer token then you need to write bearer keyword while passing the value as given below.

```
var response = await http.get(
  Uri.parse(
      'https://forms.googleapis.com/v1/forms/ID/responses'),
  headers: {
    "Authorization":"Bearer $STRING_KEY",
  });
```

And it seems like a key issue so if both of these does not work then ask your backend developer which key you need to pass in the header and put that key instead of "Authorization".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One issue is that, unless I am missing something, the google api does not give an api key, but rather an authorization json file with stuff like the client id, auth_uri, token_uri, client_secret and so on. How would you include file that as part of your header? Or does only one part of that file actually matter for the purpose of authentication?